# Is this grammatically correct sentence? My guests would really like to get up close to the animals something different and unique

Tags: american-english

Is this statement grammatically correct?

My guests would really like to get up close to the animals something different and unique

Shouldn't it be this?

My guests would really like to get up close to the animals in something different and unique way?

Source : https://youtu.be/7AWBPACJB-0?t=88

Comment: I am not going to listen to a video here. as something different and unique. As.

Comment: Neither one is a grammatically correct sentence.

Answer (score 1):

If I were transcribing this, I would do it like this:

> My guests would really like to get up close to the animals. [It's] something different and unique.

The speaker doesn't *say* the word *it's* in the sentence, but he's speaking spontaneously and drops it. It can be understood from context, but it really belongs there. The brackets indicate that I added it and the speaker intended it.

Comment: +1 for it's, but

Answer (score 0):

I have some problems with this sentence and all are "*word use*" either too much or too little. I would also suggest the use of two sentences would be preferable. A comma makes a weak conjunction.

**My guests would really like to get up close to the animals something *that is unique.***

> Unique is inherently different and to use two words with a similar meaning is not necessary.

If we use "would really like"   then the "something" becomes "something would" or some similar form.

> My guests would really like to get up close to the animals. It would be something different.

> My guests really like to get up close to the animals. It is something different.